# Email form .php script error

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a script with an email form inside, then I have a .php script  which is supposed to send the inputs in the form to another email. The problem is that when I submit the form, I get the error seen below:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "127.0.0.1" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\scripts\supFormSend.php on line 16

---

Html script:

```
<form action="supFormSend.php" method="post" id="contactForms">

    <div id="nameLabelForm">
        <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="nameInput"/>
    </div>

    <div id="emailLabelForm">
        <label for="mail">E-mail:</label><br>
        <input type="email" id="mailInput" name="mailInput"/>
    </div>

    <div id="messageLabelForm">
        <label for="msg">Support Message:</label><br>
        <textarea id="messageInput" name="messageInput"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="submitEmailButton">
        <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Send message</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

php script:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['nameInput'];
$field_email = $_POST['mailInput'];
$field_message = $_POST['messageInput'];

$mail_to = 'removed for safety';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Paste the error as text, not an image.

Comment: looks like local host, so unless you happen to have a local mail-server, you need to use an external one.

Comment: Looks like you do not have a mail server running. This will be solved once you upload your site to a web server, or you install a mail server on your machine. To prevent that error message you can type `@mail`, that will not solve the error, but it will stop it from printing that error message.

Comment: So there is no error, it is just because it has to be in a hosting panel to work? So I don't have to care about the error it makes and it will work when on the hosting panel?

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining that you are trying to send email through your local SMTP server which doesn't exist. If you are running your own SMTP server then fix the server or if you are not then you need to point PHP to a SMTP server using ini_set() or edit php.ini as indicated in the error message before calling mail().

Ex:

```
ini_set("SMTP", "mail.example.com");
ini_set("sendmail_from", "test@example.com");
ini_set("smtp_port", "25");
```

Answer (score 0):

If this site is hosted on your own server you need to download [SendEmail](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/download/) or Mercury to be able to send/receive emails on your localhost machine.